# Display stderr in a pyqt QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt, stdout, stderr

I want to capture stderr output from my PyQt script and display it in a QMessageBox.  I found these posts and tried them, but none really worked for me:

[Display python console messages in QMessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017143/display-python-console-messages-in-qmessagebox)

[Redirecting stdout and stderr to a PyQt4 QTextEdit from a secondary thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071448/redirecting-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-pyqt4-qtextedit-from-a-secondary-thread)

[PYQT: How to capture output of python's interpreter and display it in QEditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637768/pyqt-how-to-capture-output-of-pythons-interpreter-and-display-it-in-qedittext/15657432#15657432)

I was having a couple problems.  First, a single error seems to be sent as a series of separate stderr messages (at least in Python 3.4).  This caused multiple message boxes to be opened using the approaches I found, and required using `.show()` instead of `.exec()` and accumulating the separate messages into one.

Also, if a second error occurred the text from the first error remained in the new message box, even though the first message box had been closed.  I tried calling `.destroy()` and using `Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose`, but the first message box wouldn't actually go away.  So I ended up simply deleting the text from the persistent message box.

Finding a clean way to field both 'close window' and 'OK' events took some experimentation too.

Comment: Do you really want to show all text printed to `stderr` or are you looking to catch specific things (like only exceptions)?

Comment: I want to avoid having the PtQt app stall because an error occurred, and all stderr text is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I worked out something which seems to do the job and is as simple as I can make it.  If anyone has improvements or can explain the problems I've worked around here please edit the code.

This is an example which starts a simple main window with a button to create a stderr.  The error message is captured and displayed in a message box which clears correctly on 'OK' or closing.  The technique can be used with stdout too.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class StdErrHandler():
    def __init__(self):
        # To instantiate only one message box
        self.err_box = None

    def write(self, std_msg):
        # All that stderr or stdout require is a class with a 'write' method.
        if self.err_box is None:
            self.err_box = QtGui.QMessageBox()
            # Both OK and window delete fire the 'finished' signal
            self.err_box.finished.connect(self.clear)
        # A single error is sent as a string of separate stderr .write() messages, 
        # so concatenate them.
        self.err_box.setText(self.err_box.text() + std_msg)
        # .show() is used here because .exec() or .exec_() create multiple
        # MessageBoxes.
        self.err_box.show()

    def clear(self):
        # QMessageBox doesn't seem to be actually destroyed when closed, just hidden.
        # This is true even if destroy() is called or if the Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose 
        # attribute is set.  Clear text for next time.
        self.err_box.setText('')

class AppMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    """
    Main window with button to create an error
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # initialization of the superclass
        super(AppMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.create_err = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.create_err.setText("Create Error")
        self.create_err.clicked.connect(self.err_btn_clicked)

    def err_btn_clicked(self):
        # Deliberately create a stderr output
        oopsie

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    amw = AppMainWindow()
    amw.show()

    # Instantiate stderr handler class
    std_err_handler = StdErrHandler()
    # Connect stderr to the handler
    sys.stderr = std_err_handler
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDIT:**
As three_pineapples pointed out, this isn't thread-safe.  I found when I installed this in another app the message box would hang if a stderr occurred while running the app under the pydev debugger, which is probably due to this.

I rewrote it using a thread and queue, but this also hung.

Then I learned that PyQt signals & slots are thread-safe, so I rewrote it using only that.  The version below is thread-safe (I think) and runs correctly as a stand-alone script or under the debugger:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class StdErrHandler(QtCore.QObject):
    '''
    This class provides an alternate write() method for stderr messages.
    Messages are sent by pyqtSignal to the pyqtSlot in the main window.
    '''
    err_msg = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

    def write(self, msg):
        # stderr messages are sent to this method.
        self.err_msg.emit(msg)

class AppMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    '''
    Main window with button to create an error
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # initialization of the superclass
        super(AppMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        # To avoid creating multiple error boxes
        self.err_box = None

        # Single button, connect to button handler
        self.create_err = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.create_err.setText("Create Error")
        self.create_err.clicked.connect(self.err_btn_clicked)

    def err_btn_clicked(self):
        # Deliberately create a stderr output
        oopsie

    def std_err_post(self, msg):
        '''
        This method receives stderr text strings as a pyqtSlot.
        '''
        if self.err_box is None:
            self.err_box = QtGui.QMessageBox()
            # Both OK and window delete fire the 'finished' signal
            self.err_box.finished.connect(self.clear)
        # A single error is sent as a string of separate stderr .write() messages,
        # so concatenate them.
        self.err_box.setText(self.err_box.text() + msg)
        # .show() is used here because .exec() or .exec_() create multiple
        # MessageBoxes.
        self.err_box.show()

    def clear(self):
        # QMessageBox doesn't seem to be actually destroyed when closed, just hidden.
        # This is true even if destroy() is called or if the Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose
        # attribute is set.  Clear text for next time.
        self.err_box.setText('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    amw = AppMainWindow()
    amw.show()

    # Create the stderr handler and point stderr to it
    std_err_handler = StdErrHandler()
    sys.stderr = std_err_handler

    # Connect err_msg signal to message box method in main window
    std_err_handler.err_msg.connect(amw.std_err_post)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Be aware that this is not thread safe. If you have anything writing to stderr from another thread (whether that be your code, or a 3rd party library) you are likely to see random segfaults.